# How to check connectivity to ADCS Certificate Authority Server from a C# Application?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, ca, certificate-authority

I have CA server set up in windows server. I have a client code in C# for ADCS certificate management, I am able to retrieve signed certificates from an ADCS certificate authority by sending CSR using DCOM interface. Before submitting CSR to CA, I need to check whether the CA feature is running or not in CA the server. How can I implement this connectivity check in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CertSrvIsServerOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certbcli/nf-certbcli-certsrvisserveronlinew) function to check if server is online or not. If server is offline, the function will hang for about 20 seconds or so.

You can also try to call [ICertRequest::GetCAProroperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certcli/nf-certcli-icertrequest2-getcaproperty) against whatever property. Wrap this method in try/catch blocks. If server is down, an exception will be thrown.